# How can I get last inserted id using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, struts2

I want to fetch the last inserted value's id in Hibernate.

After search:

```
Long lastId = ((Long) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").uniqueResult()).longValue();
```

But the following code gives me this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Please share your thoughts!

**Solution**

```
Long lastId = ((BigInteger) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").uniqueResult()).longValue();
```

Don't forget to import:

> import java.math.BigInteger;

Comment: Mind sharing what you are going to do with this ID? As soon as you fetch the lastID it is already obsolete; any other system user/thread can update it in the timeframe that your lastId variable is in scope.

Comment: I have to store that id to another table as a foreign key id. Is there any better solution for this situation?

Comment: Yes: use JPA properly. When you insert an entity, the ID will be set in the object instance after persisting it. Get the ID from the object itself to be sure you get the correct ID. Is this for auditing purposes or something?

Comment: Uh I assumed JPA, but the same is true if you are using the Hibernate API directly.

Comment: @ALL: Get last inserted Id very easily with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561681/hibernate-get-id-after-save-object

Comment: Thanks. This solution works fine for Hibernate 4 on MySql 5.6. Here's my code: `int postID = Math.toIntExact(((BigInteger) getSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").uniqueResult()).longValue());`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Error is pretty clear. It's returning [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html) and not `long`

You have to assign it to a [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html). And get [`longValue()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_longvalue.htm) from it.

Comment: @MohitBhansali You are welcome. Please do not edit your question with answer. Mark the correct answer.

Comment: Yes obviously. But stackoverflow rules, you can't accept the answer within 5 minutes. So waiting for that only.

Answer (score 4):

```
public Integer save(Smartphones i) {
    int id = 0;
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        session.save(i);   
        id=i.getId();
        trans.commit();     
    }
    catch(HibernateException he){}
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use save which returns a Serializable object that actually is the last insert id.
Sample code:

```
Session session=this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    int result = -1;
    try {
        Serializable ser = session.save(paper);
        if (ser != null) {
            result = (Integer) ser;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

A testing run:

```
int result = paperService.save(paper);
    System.out.println("The id of the paper you just added is: "+result);
```

and here is the output:

```
The id of the paper you just added is: 3032
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the return type of `uniqueResult()` is `BigInteger` and not `Long`, you should do it like this:

```
long lastId = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
                     .uniqueResult()  // this returns a BigInteger
                     .longValue();    // this will convert it to a long value
```

The method `uniqueResult()` only returns a BigInteger because of your query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.