# Last inserted Id in Java Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

How do we get the last inserted value? Below is my function which inserts values. But I want to fetch last inserted `Id` which is auto incremented. I am using PostgreSQL

```
@Override
public int executeInsertSQLSelect(String sqlQuery) throws HibernateException {

    SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);

    logger.debug("SQL query to be executed is : " + query);

    int noOfRecordsUpdatedOrDeleted;

    try {
        noOfRecordsUpdatedOrDeleted = query.executeUpdate();


    } catch (HibernateException hbExp) {
        logger.error(String.format(
                "Error occured while executing query without Scalar"
                        + " mapping - %s ", query.getQueryString()), hbExp);
        throw hbExp;
    }
    return noOfRecordsUpdatedOrDeleted;
}
```

Comment: Hibernate session.save() return ID of inserted row.

Comment: Refer this link, this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829023/how-can-i-get-last-inserted-id-using-hibernate

Comment: Use `insert ... returning`. That will return the generated ID. Or use `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` with plain JDBC. Or run a `select lastval()` after the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ms sql server then you can make the use of `OUTPUT`

for example

```
String sqlQuery=insert into employee(employeeName) output values('john')
SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
query.getSingleResult()
```

Comment: Hi Iam using `Postgresql`

Comment: why do you you hibernate save method? Hibernate save method will return you id inserted

Comment: not able to use it.. bcos its lot of forighn key constratnts

Comment: you may get equivalent of output in postgresql, search in google